# Polygon shapefile has irregularities when viewed in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, polygon, arcgis-10.4

i am using ArcGIS 10.4 for Desktop and when i try loading my shapefiles into the arcmaps it shows extra incorrect lines in my polygon shapefile is there anyway to fix this inconsistencies automatically?

I tried using the topology tools and snap tool but it didn't fix the issue.

[image: this image shows the extra incorrect lines going through the polygons]

this is how the data was before being converted to a line 
[image: this is the image of the dots before being converted to lines]

Comment: Have you tried to [Repair Geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/repair-geometry.htm)?  I won't guarantee that will fix it but it is something that will be quick for you to try before asking you for more details.

Comment: yes i did, by the way the geometry data i got it from a website could it be that the the data itself is wrong ?

Comment: That is what I suspect.  Is what you see displayed consistent with what you see when you Start Editing polygons in a layer sourcing that shapefile?  If it is, then I would go back to the data provider to try and learn more about how it was captured and any data conversions that have occurred before it reached you.

Comment: yes when i start editing the polygons they are the same as the ones displayed

Comment: For a dataset to be a shapefile, it needs to conform to the specification.  It appears that you have data which is non-conformant. Repair Geometry can only do so much.

Comment: i converted the data from point to line could that be the cause of the problem ?

Comment: Have you tried deleting or rebuilding the spatial indexes on the shapefile?

Comment: do you mean editing the x,y coordinates ? or reloading the data to arcmap ?

Comment: @Abdullah in ArcCatalog, open the original shapefile's Properties, Indexes tab. In the Spatial Index section, click the Add or Update buttons, as appropriate.

Comment: i opened the database connection folder choose the database table that has the issue opened properties and then tried to add a unique attribute index but it gives an error  that says The CREATE UNIQUE statement has terminated  because a duplicate key was found,my privileges are select update delete and insert

Answer (score 1):

To properly convert points into lines, you need to have a unique field which has a same value for each group of points so that ArcGIS can recognize that these group of points with a same value represents one line. Without a unique field, the output lines will be mixed lines crossing each other. You refer to the [Points To Line](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/points-to-line.htm) help for more information. Please make sure you have a field with a unique value that represents group of points.

Comment: there is a shared values between groups of points

Answer (score 1):

The point to line feature in arcgis requires data in a table to be ordered on the id for the group of points, i tried sorting the data but that didn't work still the point to line feature draws extra unnecessary lines but there was less extra liens this time,so my final solution was to use the point2one plugin in QGIS and  that worked perfectly no extra liens so i saveed the shape file and imported it into arcgis and everything was good, i guess that the arcgis point to line feature had some kind of problem in finding the groups of point and not stopping drawing when moving from one group of points to another